# Removing Body Pieces from a Message

Tags: php, imap

I have a script that checks all emails received via IMAP.

THE PROBLEM:
Every time someone answers a message, a lot of information I do not want arrives:
- signature
- quote
- among others

I tried removing it one by one using the div class that holds this data.
But each e-mail server includes in a different way.
Is there any general way of returning only the message that the person actually sent without the previous pieces?

Current script I'm using to remove the pieces I do not want

```
<?
$ObjExtText             = str_get_html([Body of the email here]);

foreach($ObjExtText->find('div[class="gmail_extraquote"]') as $DadElement1) 
{

    $DadElement1->outertext         = "";

}

foreach($ObjExtText->find('div[class="gmail_extra"]') as $DadElement1) 
{

    $DadElement1->outertext         = "";

}

foreach($ObjExtText->find('div[class="gmail_signature"]') as $DadElement1) 
{

    $DadElement1->outertext         = "";

}

foreach($ObjExtText->find('div[class="gmail_quote"]') as $DadElement1) 
{

    $DadElement1->outertext         = "";

}

foreach($ObjExtText->find('div[class="yahoo_quoted"]') as $DadElement1) 
{

    $DadElement1->outertext         = "";

}

foreach($ObjExtText->find('div[class="yahoo_extraquote"]') as $DadElement1) 
{

    $DadElement1->outertext         = "";

}

foreach($ObjExtText->find('div[class="yahoo_extra"]') as $DadElement1) 
{

    $DadElement1->outertext         = "";

}

foreach($ObjExtText->find('div[class="yahoo_signature"]') as $DadElement1) 
{

    $DadElement1->outertext         = "";

}

foreach($ObjExtText->find('div[class="yahoo_quoted"]') as $DadElement1) 
{

    $DadElement1->outertext         = "";

}

echo $ObjExtText;
?>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:php] and [tag:body-parser]? Are you writing PHP or JavaScript?

Comment: I doubt that it's possible to do this in a way that works for all email providers as the signature (etc) are part of the body text as far as the IMAP protocol is concerned. It's just the "stuff" that makes up the message text, as opposed to the message header or metadata.

Comment: @Quentin Script is in PHP, my goal is to parse the body of the message, separating what is the message, what is the signature, what is the answer

Comment: @CharlesMacetko — Please *read* the tags you use. [tag:body-parser] has a very specific meaning.

Comment: I see several helpdesk systems, which do exactly that.
Example: Zendesk

Where the exchange of messages between the parties is done via email, but in the history of the call is only the message that was actually sent (this is what I'm trying to do in a helpdesk system of mine)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks, I removed the wrong tag

Comment: In general, no.  This is done heuristically by inspecting the output of a LOT of different clients and writing parsing for each.  Zendesk probably gets it wrong occasionally when people use an oddball client.  Choose your top 10 clients, and write code for each one.  There _may_ exist libraries for this.  IMAP will not help you; the body is opaque bytes to it.

Comment: Max is right.  You may be able to make it work for certain email editors (like your gmail and yahoo examples above), but many if not most of the email editors out there will not be so kind as to define which part of the message body is what.